# Oracle Apex: Interactive grid results in server error ORA-01403: No data found

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I have an interactive grid with a status column. If I change the status from active to archived, a plsql script moves the record from the active table to an archive table. Now, the interactive grid results in a server error "ORA-01403: No data found". I assume, the problem is, that the displayed row is not more available in the source table of the grid.

I tried to use the change selection event of the grid, to refresh the whole grid, but it fails. The server error raises before the grid event occurs. Any ideas to solve this problem?

Comment: Try putting an exeception for NO_DATA_FOUND and display it.

Comment: In addition, one option is instead to use the save button in the grid toolbar, to create a new button with a submit action. But I think it is not a good solution to refresh the whole page after each status change.

Comment: I tried a exception handling for NO_DATA_FOUND, but not successful, because the server error results from an internal ajax process of the grid and I don't know how to handle such errors.